# Adding double quotes in <a> using C#

Tags: c#

I have below code behind in c#

```
        if (Session["cmpDictionaryTitle"]!= null)
                {
                    downloadLinks.Text += @"<li><a onclick='pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary', 'spanish');' target ='_blank' href=" + Session["cmpDictionaryTitle"] + ">" + GetResourceString("c_DictionaryPDFName") + "</a></li>";
                }
```

I am trying to make below `<a>` link as shown below:

```
<li><a target ="_blank" href="/spa/Images/Diccionario_tcm25-18044.pdf" onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary', 'spanish');">Diccionario de Español-Inglés GRATIS</a></li>
```

However my c# code is generating below output when html page get renders, the reason is that I am not able to put proper quotes in my code behind.

```
<li><a );="" spanish="" ,="" dictionary="" onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent(" href="/spa/Images/Diccionario_tcm25-18044.pdf" target="_blank">Diccionario de Español-Inglés GRATIS</a></li>
```

Can you please suggest how can I achieve above result in code behind.

Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a double-quote in a string built in code, either:

- Escape the double-quote character
  like this: "\"".
- Escape the double-quote character like this:
  """" (when using `@` to create a verbatim
  string literal).

Examples:

```
// These are both rendered as <a target="_blank" />
Response.Write("<a target =\"_blank\" />");
Response.Write(@"<a target =""_blank"" />");
```

Here's your original code using backslash-escaped double-quotes for all the attributes (I've chosen the first approach and removed the leading `@`):

```
if (Session["cmpDictionaryTitle"]!= null) {
    downloadLinks.Text += "<li><a onclick=\"pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary', 'spanish');\" target =\"_blank\" href=\"" + Session["cmpDictionaryTitle"] + "\">" + GetResourceString("c_DictionaryPDFName") + "</a></li>";
}
```

Finally, I recommend reading Jon Skeet's excellent article "[Strings in .NET and C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html)."

Answer (score 1):

```
<a 
    onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary', 'spanish');" 
    target ="_blank" 
    href="<%= Server.HtmlEncode((string)Session["cmpDictionaryTitle"]) %>">
    <%= Server.HtmlEncode(GetResourceString("c_DictionaryPDFName")) %>
</a>
```

---

UPDATE:

You could also build tags using [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx):

```
var tag = new XElement("li", 
    new XElement("a",
        new XAttribute("onclick", "pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary', 'spanish');"),
        new XAttribute("target", "_blank"),
        new XAttribute("href", Session["cmpDictionaryTitle"]),
        new XText(GetResourceString("c_DictionaryPDFName"))
    )
);

downloadLinks.Text += tag.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks for your reply its still showing error in string? I have updated the question code again, please have a look and suggest

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the above issue with below code:

```
downloadLinks.Text = string.Format("<li> <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{0}\" onclick=\"pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary','spanish');\">{1}</a> </li>",Session["cmpPDFLink"],GetResourceString("c_DictionaryPDFName"));
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is using single quotes for the attribute quotes, and within the value itself, so just change one of them to use double quotes, e.g.:

```
<a onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary', 'spanish');" ...
```

Comment: Hi Jonow, it is the same as above example, please suggest

Comment: No its different, you need to change:

downloadLinks.Text += @"<li><a onclick='pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary', 'spanish');' ...

to

downloadLinks.Text += @"<li><a onclick=\"pageTracker._trackEvent('dictionary', 'spanish');\" ...

- note the change in quotes